# NavigationSplitView not updating

Tags: ipad, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationsplitview

Can someone please help me why the `NavigationLink` is not working as intended?
As shown down below (in the code) I use the `MarkdownWebView(url: <url>)` with 3 different URL’s.

But when I want to switch between them, the view doesn’t update.
If I open another view in between it’s working.
And on the iPhone (`NavigationStack`) it also works.

#### The Problem

[image: GIF of issue]

#### My Code:

```swift
Section("Legal") {
    NavigationLink {
        MarkdownWebView(url: "https://<url>/privacy.md", scrollbar: false)
            .navigationTitle("Privacy Policy")
    } label: {
        Text("")
            .font(.custom(CustomFonts.FADuotone, size: 20))
            .frame(width: 30)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
        Text(String(localized: "Privacy Policy", comment: "/"))
    }
    NavigationLink {
        MarkdownWebView(url: "https://<url>/tos.md", scrollbar: false)
            .navigationTitle("Terms of use")
    } label: {
        Text("")
            .font(.custom(CustomFonts.FADuotone, size: 20))
            .frame(width: 30)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
        Text(String(localized: "Terms of Service", comment: "/"))
    }
    NavigationLink {
        MarkdownWebView(url: "https://<url>/licenses.md", scrollbar: false)
            .navigationTitle("Licenses")
    } label: {
        Text("")
            .font(.custom(CustomFonts.FADuotone, size: 20))
            .frame(width: 30)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
        Text(String(localized: "Licenses", comment: "/"))
    }
}
```

#### NavigagationSplitView

This is what the NavigationSplitView looks like:

```swift
var body: some View {
      NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $navigationVM.selectedColumnVisibility) {
          column1Form
              .navigationTitle(String(localized: "Dashboard", comment: "/"))
              .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.large)
      } content: {
          secondForm
      }detail: {
          detailForm
      }
      .navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced)
}
```

```swift
@ViewBuilder
  var secondForm: some View {
      switch navigationVM.selectedCategory {
      case .findWineries: findWineries()
      case .profile: ProfileView()
      case .stats: StatisticsView()
      case .favWines: FavWineView()
      case .favWineries: FavWineriesView()
      case .cellar: CellarView()
      case .orders: OrderListView()
  ->  case .settings: SettingsView()
      case .none: Text("")
      }
  }
  
  @ViewBuilder
  var detailForm: some View {
      switch navigationVM.selectedDetail {
      case .map: MapView()
      case .order: Text("orderTest")
      case .orderDetail: OrderDetailView(Status: .delivered)
      case .none: Text("")
      }
}
```

On the second column of the SplitView I navigate to the SettingsView() (marked in the code with an arrow).

From there (SettingsView) I want to push the third row with the NavigationLink.

This works fine if I push separate Views. But it doesn’t work with the same View and different parameters (as shown in the post above).

#### MarkdownWebView()

```swift
import SwiftUI
import MarkdownUI

struct MarkdownWebView: View {
    @State var url: String
    @State var scrollbar: Bool
    @State var error: Bool = false
    
    @State private var fileContent: String? = nil
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let content = fileContent {
                ScrollView(showsIndicators: scrollbar) {
                    Markdown(content)
                }
            } else {
                if (error) {
                    VStack(spacing: 20) {
                        Text("")
                            .font(.custom(CustomFonts.FADuotone, size: 100, relativeTo: .body))
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                        Text("Document not found")
                            .font(.title)
                    }
                } else {
                    VStack(spacing: 20) {
                        ProgressView()
                        Text("loading")
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        .onAppear {
            loadMarkdownFile(url: url)
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    private func loadMarkdownFile(url: String) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            guard let fileUrl = URL(string: url) else {
                print("File not found")
                self.error = true
                return
            }
            do {
                let content = try String(contentsOf: fileUrl)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.fileContent = content
                }
            } catch {
                self.error = true
                print("Error reading file: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to show the whole `NavigationSplitView`

Comment: @ChrisR I added the infos above :)

Comment: try removing `@State` from var `url` and var `scrollbar` in `MarkdownWebView`. They are passed in parameters and should not be State.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the way you use `NavigationLink` the `.onAppear` in `MarkdownWebView` is only called once for the first view. So the content doesn't refresh on other selections, because the view is already visible and `.onAppear` isn't called again.

I can suggest two options:

**1. quick and dirty**
Give each call of `MarkdownWebView` a different `.id` which forces a redraw:

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section("Legal") {
                NavigationLink {
                    MarkdownWebView(url: "https://www.lipsum.com", scrollbar: false)
                        .navigationTitle("Privacy Policy")
                        .id(1) // here
                } label: {
                    Text("")
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        .frame(width: 30)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    Text(String(localized: "Privacy Policy", comment: "/"))
                }
                NavigationLink {
                    MarkdownWebView(url: "https://www.apple.com", scrollbar: false)
                        .navigationTitle("Terms of use")
                        .id(2) // here
                } label: {
                    Text("")
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        .frame(width: 30)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    Text(String(localized: "Terms of Service", comment: "/"))
                }
                NavigationLink {
                    MarkdownWebView(url: "https://www.google.com", scrollbar: false)
                        .navigationTitle("Licenses")
                        .id(3) // here
               } label: {
                    Text("")
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        .frame(width: 30)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    Text(String(localized: "Licenses", comment: "/"))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**2. new SwiftUI navigation logic**
Use the new init of `NavigationLink` with value and provide a `.navigationDestination`.
I used Int values here (1,2,3) but you can (and should) also use enum values.

```
struct SettingsView2: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section("Legal") {
                NavigationLink(value: 1) { // value 1
                    Text("")
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        .frame(width: 30)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    Text(String(localized: "Privacy Policy", comment: "/"))
                }
                NavigationLink(value: 2) { // value 2
                    Text("")
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        .frame(width: 30)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    Text(String(localized: "Terms of Service", comment: "/"))
                }
                NavigationLink(value: 3) { // value 3
                    Text("")
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        .frame(width: 30)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    Text(String(localized: "Licenses", comment: "/"))
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { value in // define destinations based on value
            switch value {
            case 1:
                MarkdownWebView(url: "https://www.lipsum.com", scrollbar: false)
                    .navigationTitle("Privacy Policy")
            case 2:
                MarkdownWebView(url: "https://www.apple.com", scrollbar: false)
                    .navigationTitle("Terms of use")
            case 3:
                MarkdownWebView(url: "https://www.google.com", scrollbar: false)
                    .navigationTitle("Licenses")
            default: Text("nothing")
            }
        }
    }
}
```